# Какой вид графики удобен для самостоятельного рисования нехудожником?

Tags: unity3d, графика, 3d, 2d

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот например есть пиксель-арт или а-ля Майнкрафт, там даже не художник может что-то вполне достойное создавать, а какие ещё есть направления графического представления игры где очень просто создавать модели? Интересует как 2d так и 3d. Видел ещё такой вид графики - как будто всё упрощённое. В общем перечислите пожалуйста, какие бывают виды графики, где создание контента - дело несложное и не требует больших затрат по времени.

- пиксель-арт
- воксельная графика
- лоу поли?
- мультяшная графика?
- ...

Comment: Можно добавить пункт "profit" еще.

Comment: в любой графике создание контента дело несложное и не требует больших временных затрат. А вот создание **хорошего** и **востребованного** контента требует таланта и времени в любом виде графики. Каляку-маляку любой болван может нарисовать в любой технике. А ты попробуй нарисуй что-нибудь интересное

Comment: но в пиксель-арте по сравнению с другими видами графики это требует минимальных затрат, вопрос именно в этом

Comment: зачем вы закрываете вопрос? просто список составить из видов графики где легко можно создавать модели, в чем тут неоднозначность? модель пиксель-арта сделать ПРОЩЕ чем модель с миллионами полигонов ААА-графики

Comment: кстати, зачем тег unity?